# Como funciona la recursion?

Tags: javascript, if, recursión

alguien podria decirme como funciona la recursion? Paso a paso si es posible, no llego a entenderla, como no puede ejecutarse la funcion, como que coge nuevos valores hasta que llegue a cero, ahi retornara 1 y de nuevo a la otra funcion?
Gracias

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    // This is it! Recursion!!
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
}
console.log(factorial(4)); // OUTPUT => 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Una *funcion recursiv*a, es una *funcion que se llama a si misma*.

**Pero de que sirven?**, no es mas ni menos eficiente ya que depende del lenguaje de programacion y de la implementacion del algoritmo, entonces ?

Realizan un codigo mas limpio y elegante.

**Y, como se conforma una funcion recursiva?**

Una funcion recursiva se conforma de una condicion base, que probablemente habras escuchado, pero que significa ?

Significa que obviamente la funcion tiene que parar en algun momento, si no la funcion se llamara infinitas veces..

Y ademas estara conformado por su algoritmo en si.

p.e :

### Factorial de un numero:

**Recursiva v/s Ciclo**

Recursiva:

```js
function _f(number){
 if(number === 1) return number;
 return number * _f(number -1);
}
console.log(_f(5));
```

```js
function _fFor (number){
 var acc = 1;
 while (number > 1) {
 acc *= number;
 number--;
 }
 return acc;
}
console.log(_fFor(5));
```

En el caso de sacar el factorial de un numero, como funciona?

El factorial de un numero funciona asi:

```
 n = n * (n-1) + (n-1) * (n-2) .... 1 Hasta llegar a 1
```

Hasta llegar a 1, ya que si multiplicaras por 0, daria siempre 0 (cualquiera numero * 0 es = 0)

### Analizamos tu funcion:

```
function factorial(n) { // 1° Recibe el numero al cual calculara el factorial
  /* Supondremos que necesitamos el factorial de 4 */
  if (n === 0) { // 3° cuando sea 0, NO multiplica por 0, osino anularia todo, sino por 1 que es el neutro multiplicativo
    return 1;
  } else {
    // This is it! Recursion!!
    return n * factorial(n - 1); // 2° Retornara 4 * 4-1 , ya que la funcion factorial en si retorna el n -1 y asi hasta llegar a 0
  }
}
```

Si te preguntas, porque retorna n * factorial (n-1) es porque debe `"acumularlo"`, entonces, el valor se va acumulando internamente y luego en el caso base, osea en este caso cuando vale 0, retorna el valor totalmente acumulado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas importante para utilizar  la recursividad es tener una condición de salida clara en tu caso

> n === 0
>    asi evitaras entrar en un ciclo infinito.

como segunda parte debes de ejecutar la misma función en tu caso 
`return n * factorial(args);`

y por último tienes que hacer algo para que tu condición `n === 0` se cumpla en tu caso `(n - 1)`

Para finalizar la recursividad es ejecutar una misma función hasta que algo se cumpla 
Tu ejemplo en pseudocódigo se leería así :

Mientras que mi  entrada sea diferente de 0 multiplicalo por n y restale 1

Entonces lo que tu función estaría haciendo es

- Si 4 <> 0 
    4 * funcion(4-1) = 4
- Si 3 <> 0 
  3 * function(3-1) = 3
- Si 2 <> 0 
  2 * function(2-1) = 2
- Si 1 <> 0 
     1 * function(1-1) = 1

Después vemos que lo que hace la función es multiplicar los resultados 
primero desde el más bajo ya que la función se anida

- 1 * 2 = 2
- 2 * 3 = 6
- 6 * 4 = 24

Answer (score 0):

### Definición

> El factorial de un número es el producto de dicho número por todos los anteriores menores que él hasta llegar al cero. Por definición el factorial del número 0 es 1.

---

El resultado se representa por una notación abreviada que es el símbolo de cierre de exclamación (!).

Dicho esto, el factorial del número 5 sería:

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

### Factorial Javascript sin pensar demasiado...

Rápidamente de la definición podríamos codificar la función factorial Javascript de la siguiente forma, con un bucle decreciente del argumento hasta llegar al 1 o ascendente desde el 1 hasta el número deseado que recibimos como argumento del que queremos calcular el factorial Javascript. El cero no haría falta considerarlo pues el su factorial es 1

```
 function factorial (n) {
var total = 1; 
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    total = total * i; 
}
return total; 
}
```

### Observemos la definición

Si leemos bien la definición de factorial como número resultado de multiplicarse con todos los anteriores. En el ejemplo y siendo la multiplicación una operación asociativa (también lo es conmutativa, pero no importa para lo que queremos señalar):

---

Así que podemos calcular el factorial Javascript como una función recursiva, es decir, que hace referencia a sí misma multiplicando el argumento por el factorial javascript del número precedente:

```
 function factorialRecursivo (n) { 
  if (n == 0){ 
    return 1; 
  }
  return n * factorialRecursivo (n-1); 
 }
```

Fuente [Linea de Código](http://lineadecodigo.com/javascript/factorial-javascript/)